# Too many neighbors when pathfinding in Sparse Voxel Octree

Tags: path-finding, octree

Imagine we have upto 9 or so layers (that is depth), and due to some big colliding platform in the level, one of the empty nodes close to the root have all much smaller nodes as neighbors at one of its faces. If my calculations are not wrong, in the worst case scenario the number of neighbors on a face would be equal to power(2, absolute(depthA - depthB) * 2). For example, power(2, absolute(8 - 2) * 2) = 4096 little neighbors in direction of only one of the faces of the bigger node.

I'm implementing a linear tree (just saving all location codes in a set). I know how to find neighbors. I have no idea how to deal with high number of neighbors in cases like this when running A*. Both, finding all neighbors and iterating over all of them would take too much time.

I have taken a look at the GDC "Getting of the NavMesh by Daniel Brewer", but their example for neighbors of different sizes was only for difference of 1, which would return only 4 neighbors per face.

Comment: Think of it this way: You have not gained 4096 neighbour nodes to visit. You had those all along. What you've done with the sparseness of the octree is saved yourself from having to visit those 4096 neighbour nodes from 4096 different parent nodes, or scanning along a chain of 4096 siblings to reach each one. Instead they're all directly accessible in one hop from a *single* parent node. So you've still reduced the amount of nodes you need to visit in total. It's just that in areas with dense detail, you save less than in areas with sparse detail.

Comment: I don't know how to use A* on it. I don't think A* is designed to iterate and compare thousands of edges.

Comment: That's exactly what A* does. What would give you the impression that it cannot do this? Did you encounter a specific error when you tried?

Comment: It's not at a phase that I can test it yet. I just imagined A* running. On regular voxels (all same size), it would compare only 6 edges per step (for only faces), and might test less edges in total to reach the goal, right? Otherwise I'll have to calculate distance of more than 4096 edges to the goal in a single step, even if they'll be useless later on. Am I wrong? Doesn't it make A* less meaningful? Or is this just a delusional feeling? I think A* exploits hierarchy.

Comment: If you haven't tested yet, then you don't know if there's a real problem yet. Your analysis is too zoomed-in to be a reliable guide. You don't want to compare the worst case for a single node, because that has high variability in a sparse octree and most nodes won't hit the worst case. What you want to do is compare the total cost of the search. If you're thousands of cells away from your goal, A* has to compute distances for thousands of cells *anyway*. Whether it does many of these computations from a single parent, or from thousands of different parents, does not change the total cost.